How do I set up a UI Aceternity component in a preexisting Next.js project?
I watched a video and found out about UI Acernity and it feels like a godsend. However, I am struggling with setting it up. I have read some articles and watched some videos but it feels like I am learning how to code for the first time again and I have no clue what I am doing. I am so clueless I nearly deleted my project directory by accident.
So I was wondering if anyone could explain how to do this. I am trying to follow the guides on https://ui.aceternity.com/components/background-boxes which is the component I want to add, but typescript is tripping me up. Could anyone explain to me how to do this?
I tried downloading dependencies, then adding a util file, and then updating my tailwind.config.js file, but I kept on running into an error or some issue that was different everytime. I also tried installing shadcn and doing it that way but that led to even more issues.
